# PHP no encuentra una clase

Tags: php, composer

estoy trabajando con un paradigma MVC en el que tengo un controlador que accede a dos modelos para recoger datos de la BD. El problema que tengo es que la primera clase la encuentra sin problemas y trae los datos bien, pero para el segundo me pone que no encuentra la clase, más en concreto el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las clases son las siguientes:

**ExpedienteController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;

use MVC\Router;
use Model\Expedientes;
use Model\Pliegos;

class ExpedienteController {
    public static function index(Router $router){
        $limite = 10;
        $expedientes = Expedientes::get($limite);
        foreach ($expedientes as $expediente){
            $pliego = Pliegos::get($expediente->expedientes);
            $expediente->pliegos[] = $pliego;
        }

        $router->render('/expedientes', [
            'expedientes' => $expedientes
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Expedientes.php**

```
<?php

namespace Model;

class Expedientes extends ActiveRecord {
    // Base de datos
    protected static $tabla = 'tbl_expedientes';
    protected static $columnasDB = ['expedientes', 'numero_expediente', 'title', 'link', 'objeto_contrato', 'valor_estimado', 'presupuesto_sin_impuestos', 'presupuesto_con_impuestos', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'duracion', 'unitcode', 'typecode', 'subtypecode', 'num_lotes'];

    public $expedientes;
    public $numero_expediente;
    public $title;
    public $link;
    public $objeto_contrato;
    public $valor_estimado;
    public $presupuesto_sin_impuestos;
    public $presupuesto_con_impuestos;
    public $start_date;
    public $end_date;
    public $duracion;
    public $unitcode;
    public $typecode;
    public $subtypecode;
    public $num_lotes;
    public $pliegos = [];

    public function __construct($args = []){
        $this->expedientes = $args['expedientes'] ?? '';
        $this->numero_expediente = $args['numero_expediente'] ?? '';
        $this->title = $args['title'] ?? '';
        $this->link = $args['link'] ?? '';
        $this->objeto_contrato = $args['objeto_contrato'] ?? '';
        $this->valor_estimado = $args['valor_estimado'] ?? '';
        $this->presupuesto_sin_impuestos = $args['presupuesto_sin_impuestos'] ?? '';
        $this->presupuesto_con_impuestos  = $args['presupuesto_con_impuestos '] ?? '';
        $this->start_date = $args['start_date'] ?? '';
        $this->end_date = $args['end_date'] ?? '';
        $this->duracion = $args['duracion'] ?? '';
        $this->unitcode = $args['unitcode'] ?? '';
        $this->typecode = $args['typecode'] ?? '';
        $this->subtypecode = $args['subtypecode'] ?? '';
        $this->num_lotes = $args['num_lotes'] ?? '';
    }

    // Obtiene determinado numero de registros
    public static function get($limite){
        $query = "SELECT expedientes, numero_expediente, title, link, objeto_contrato, valor_estimado, presupuesto_sin_impuestos, presupuesto_con_impuestos, start_date, end_date, duracion, unitcode,";
        $query .= " tbl_type_code.nombre AS typecode, tbl_subtype_code.nombre AS subtypecode, num_lotes FROM " . static::$tabla;
        $query .= " INNER JOIN tbl_type_code ON tbl_expedientes.typecode = tbl_type_code.code";
        $query .= " INNER JOIN tbl_subtype_code ON tbl_expedientes.subtypecode = tbl_subtype_code.code";
        $query .= " LIMIT " . $limite;

        $resultado = self::consultarSQL($query);
        return $resultado;
    }
}
```

**Pliegos.php**

```
<?php

namespace Model;

class Pliegos extends ActiveRecord {
    // Base de datos
    protected static $tabla = 'tbl_pliegos';
    protected static $columnasDB = ['pliegos', 'id', 'uri', 'document_hash', 'file_name', 'tipo_pliego', 'expedientes'];

    public $pliegos;
    public $id;
    public $uri;
    public $document_hash;
    public $file_name;
    public $tipo_pliego;
    public $expedientes;

    public function __construct($args = []){
        $this->pliegos = $args['pliegos'] ?? '';
        $this->id = $args['id'] ?? '';
        $this->uri = $args['uri'] ?? '';
        $this->document_hash = $args['document_hash'] ?? '';
        $this->file_name = $args['file_name'] ?? '';
        $this->tipo_pliego = $args['tipo_pliego'] ?? '';
        $this->expedientes = $args['expedientes'] ?? '';
    }

    // Obtiene los pliegos correspondientes a un expediente (se le pasa de argumento el ID del entry)
    public static function get($expedientes){
        $query = "SELECT tbl_pliegos.id, tbl_pliegos.uri, tbl_tipo_pliego.tipo FROM licitacion.tbl_pliegos";
        $query .= " INNER JOIN tbl_tipo_pliego ON tbl_pliegos.tipo_pliego = tbl_tipo_pliego.id";
        $query .= " WHERE expedientes = " . $expedientes;
        
        $resultado = self::consultarSQL($query);
        return $resultado;
    }
}
```

**autoload.php (compo**

```
{
    "name": "XX",
    "description": "POO",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "X",
            "email": "X"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Model\\": "./models",
            "MVC\\": "./",
            "Controllers\\": "./controllers"
        }
    }
}
```

Pienso que puede ser un error del autoload, pero no sé como depurarlo para saber qué está fallando exactamente. Los namespace están bien puestos, y las llamadas también desde el controlador. No entiendo qué puede estar mal. Gracias.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Os dejo la estructura de carpetas y archivos del proyecto. Yo, personalmente, no veo nada raro. Sigo sin encontrar el error que produce esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También os dejo la captura de pantalla de un `composer dump-autoload`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando ejecutas `composer dump-autoload` te da algun error?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos el contenido de la carpeta donde están las clases?

Comment: Ya lo dejé en la actualización de la pregunta. Gracias por vuestro tiempo :)

Comment: ¿Tú estás incluyendo el archivo autoload en el punto de entrada de la aplicación?

Comment: Si, en app.php lo tengo incluido.